# SOLR Spatial use of NumericRangeQuery

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I was reading the following article, http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/the-state-and-future-of-spatial-search/, which states,

> A SpatialFilter which uses NumericRangeQuery based bounding boxes to easily filter out documents outside of a certain range.

Investigating a bit, I don't see that actually happening in the SOLR source code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.1.0/org/apache/solr/schema/LatLonType.java

I.e. at line 201 I see:

```
Query latRange = latField.getType().getRangeQuery(parser, latField,
    String.valueOf(latMin),String.valueOf(latMax),true, true);
```

Which seems to use a TermRangeQuery. Crossing over to the NumericRangeQuery javadoc here http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html, it appears that NumericRangeQuery is definitely preferable, as it's much much faster:

> Comparisons of the different types of RangeQueries on an index with about 500,000 docs showed that TermRangeQuery in boolean rewrite mode (with raised BooleanQuery clause count) took about 30-40 secs to complete, TermRangeQuery in constant score filter rewrite mode took 5 secs and executing this class took <100ms to complete (on an Opteron64 machine, Java 1.5, 8 bit precision step).

I really want the uber fast NumericRangeQuery but it doesn't look like I get it out of the box. I must be missing something.

EDIT:

LatLonType from schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

Which is I think, the default that ships with Solr...

Comment: Can you paste the definition of your LatLon field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `bbox` and `geofilt` spatial filters will use `createSpatialQuery` whereas the default (Lucene) query parser (using syntax `[start TO end]`) will use `getRangeQuery`.

In both cases, these methods leverage `getRangeQuery` on the sub fields. The type of range query will depend on this sub field type, which is configurable using the `subFieldType` or `subFieldSuffix` attribute of the LatLon field type. If you want to use numeric range queries, just use an instance of `TrieDoubleField`.

For example

```
<fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="latLon" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_latLon"/>
<field name="lat_lon" type="latLon" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_latLon" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I also added an example. If you use the default configuration, then you are probably already using a NumericRangeQuery.

Comment: so you're saying if the dynamic type for _coordinate is tdouble then it uses NumericRangeQuery?

Comment: Exactly. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.1.0/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieField.java#TrieField.getRangeQuery%28org.apache.solr.search.QParser%2Corg.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29